# Can POSTGIS 2.0 be install with POSTGRES 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 OS at the moment?

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, ubuntu

This question is more about environment set up.

At the current moment, March 4th 2013, can POSTGIS2.0 be install with POSTGRES 9.2?

I check their website out and to my understanding it is not possible...

```
 http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall#PostGIS2.0
```

I hope that's not the case. Any one can tell and point out the instruction how to install POSTGIS 2.0 on POSTGRES 9.2 on Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Anything is possible if you're willing to compile from source.

Comment: Recently I had a problem installing PostGis using the commands @MikeToews suggested (only using postgres 9.1) due to a missing package. Not sure if this is your problem, but it threw me off for a few hours until I realized I need to repair the packages using `apt-get update --fix-missing`

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS normally supports PostgreSQL 9.1. To get PostgreSQL 9.2 would require another method.

Try installing PostgreSQL 9.2 using instructions from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

After the repository has been added, [follow these instructions](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204src), with one modification:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential postgresql-9.2 postgresql-server-dev-9.2 libxml2-dev libproj-dev libjson0-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl docbook-mathml
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be installed from repositories, you may need to download and install from source.

Try this:

**Install GEOS(for topology support)**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
tar xfj geos-3.3.9.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.3.9
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd..
```

**Install PostGIS 2.0**

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
tar xfz postgis-2.0.6.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.0.6
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo make comments-install
```

Source: [how to install postgresql 9.2 + postgis 2.0](http://technobytz.com/install-postgresql-9-2-postgis-2-0-ubuntu.html)