# Installing postgis on postgresql 9.1 not working

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Postgis 2.0 on a perfectly functionig postgresql 9.1.10 database.

I installed the package via:

```
richard@srv1:/$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis postgis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
postgis is already the newest version.
postgresql-9.1-postgis is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

With out any errors.
Then I try to add postgis as an extension to an existing (empty) database, with:

```
 dev=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
 ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

If I look at the location the file does not exist.

What am I missing? I can't figure it out. If I google I only get ancient results....

Where can I find the version of the installed postgis? As I'm not able to do a `SELECT PostGIS_version();`

Environment: Postgresql 9.1.10, Ubuntu 12.04

**Update**

I'm willing to install postgis2.0; apparently I have 1.5 installed. After purging that version I added the [repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt)

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
```

After trying to install the package via

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

it ends with:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal1_1.9.0-3.1~pgdg12.4+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update 2**

It appears because of the naming of the packages, it installed the wrong architecture type package. 
But I ended up using [this website](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204#Completeinstallationusingacombinationofpackagesandsources) and these steps after making sure I had gdal>= 1.9.0 and GEOS >=3.3.3:

```
wget http://postgis.refractions.net/download/postgis-2.0.0.tar.gz
tar xfvz postgis-2.0.0.tar.gz
cd postgis-2.0.0
./configure --with-gui

make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo make comments-install


sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```

**TADA**

```
durham=#  select PostGIS_full_version();
NOTICE:  Function postgis_topology_scripts_installed() not found. Is topology support enabled and topology.sql installed?
                                                                     postgis_full_version                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="2.0.0 r9605" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.1, released 2012/05/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER
(1 row)
```

Comment: It probably would be useful to include some information about your operating system and installation environment.  Also, add appropriate tags for such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, you don't have PostGIS 2.0 but 1.5 (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/precise/postgresql-9.1-postgis)

By doing `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` you're trying to initialize from PostgreSQL with the new loading mechanism a PostGIS version (1.5) that do not support it and in this case, you will need to follow the [PostGIS 1.5 official doc](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id354617)

If you need 2.0, follow various instructions already available in previous gis.stack.exchange.com answers e.g [Install PostGIS on Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48369/install-postgis-on-ubuntu-12-04) or [Can POSTGIS 2.0 be install with POSTGRES 9.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 OS at the moment?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53378/can-postgis-2-0-be-install-with-postgres-9-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-os-at-the-moment)

**Edit due to changes in question:**

When I look in the repository (http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main), I see you can get different PostGIS versions for different PostgreSQL versions, so `sudo apt-get install postgis` is not enough clear for the package manager

Did you try?

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0
```

Comment: A so the version is the problem. I've tried to install the 2.0 version but ended up with another error. See my updated question.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need install postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts

In Ubuntu or Debian you need to run the following command as root:

apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts

This adds the files needed to create the postgis extensions