# Problem installing PostGIS on Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, ubuntu

I've installed PostgreSQL 9.1 and postgis on Ubuntu Server 13.10 as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository-ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
apt-get update
apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

then I tried creating some special columns allowed by postgis like a geometry column but that doesn't exist. I did some search and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459361/postgis-install

so I tried:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
```

but I got this error: could not open extension control file "usr/share/postgresql"

Comment: Are you the same person as Dan on Stack Overflow? With this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21498244/398670  ? (You know you can sync your accounts between Stack Exchange sites, right, you don't have to make a different one on each site).

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions seem to be outdated. Please, read [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76544/installing-postgis-on-postgresql-9-1-not-working) for a reason of your errors, and for a better install way.

See these links also, for a quick way:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL 9.1 And PostGIS 2 On Ubuntu 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318652/configuring-postgresql-9-1-and-postgis-2-on-ubuntu-13)
- [Installing Postgis On Ubuntu](http://gingerjoos.com/blog/code/installing-postgis-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail)

Comment: When I tried to install `postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0-scripts` i get that it's already installed. but couldn't figure out how to activate it or something

Comment: The tutorial says that now: "... you should be able to connect to a database with psql and be able to run this:

**create extension postgis;**

If this works, then you should be good to go!"

Comment: when I run `psql -U postgres -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis"` I get: `ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/sharepostgresql/9.1extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

Comment: Then, try to spatially enabling your database using enabler scripts. Follow **Enabler Scripts / Template** section instructions from here: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1204src

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following approach for installing postgis:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

Are you sure that it all installed without errors?

Comment: after update command i got this error: `E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead` and it's gone when i removed the repository

Comment: Can you try and run `apt-get update --fix-missing` to see if something was not downloaded/installed properly ?

Comment: 404 Not found for: `W: Faild to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages` and `W: Faild to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages`

Comment: ok, looks like the `ppa` does not exist for this version of ubuntu. I have only tested the above on 12.04

Comment: well, if i keep getting this problems i might be back to Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the [ubuntugis-stable ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=postgis&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) does not contain a postgis package for saucy.

However, the [ubuntugis-unstable ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable/+packages?field.name_filter=postgis&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) does. I install packages from the unstable ppa by default. I feel like the stable ppa is very slow to support the latest versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

With 13.10 (albeit the desktop version) I found that I had to build PostGIS 2.x from source, as the `ubuntugis-unstable` PPA does not include the *.sql scripts necessary to register the extension in and populate a template database (I think `mattmakesmaps` alluded to this [in his answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85081/12764)). Here are the basic steps for building PostGIS 2.1 from source on top of PostgreSQL 9.1. This approach assumes that you installed PostgreSQL 9.1 from the package (`postgresql-9.1`) and also installed GEOS, Proj, and GDAL form source or can otherwise find the shared libraries.

```
# Install dependencies
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

cd /usr/local/ && sudo mkdir postgis && sudo chown [username] postgis && cd postgis
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz && rm postgis-2.1.0.tar.gz && cd postgis-2.1.0
sudo ./configure --with-projdir=/usr/local/proj/proj-4.8.0/
make
sudo make install

# Configure template database
POSTGIS_TEMPLATE=postgis-2.1.0
POSTGRESQL_VER=9.1
sudo su -c "createdb $POSTGIS_TEMPLATE" - postgres 
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate='true' WHERE datname='$POSTGIS_TEMPLATE';" 
sudo -u postgres psql -d $POSTGIS_TEMPLATE -f /usr/share/postgresql/$POSTGRESQL_VER/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
sudo -u postgres psql -d $POSTGIS_TEMPLATE -c "GRANT ALL ON geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;"
sudo -u postgres psql -d $POSTGIS_TEMPLATE -c "GRANT SELECT ON spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;"
```

If you want to install `shp2pgsql` you'll need to do the following.

```
# Put the loader `shp2pgsql` on your path; likely not done when building from source
cd /usr/local/postgis/postgis-2.1.0/loader
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/postgis/postgis-2.1.0/loader/shp2pgsql /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the install instructions found here:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21UbuntuPGSQL93Apt

I've had no problem with these on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, and even Cinnamon Mint!